# Splitting multiple string row to different rows

Tags: string, postgresql, split

I have a table in Postgresql. one of the fields have multiple string, I want to put this string in different rows.
I used:

```
id  lng  lat  descriptions
1   0.98 51   walk, wedding, bus
```

and insert into another table like this:

```
id  lng   lat  descriptions
1   0.98   51   walk
1   0.98   51   wedding
1   0.98   51   bus
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unnest()` with [`regexp_split_to_array()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html):

```
WITH tb(id,lng,lat,descriptions) AS ( VALUES
  (1,0.98,51,'walk, wedding, bus')
)
SELECT id,lng,lat,trim(unnest(regexp_split_to_array(descriptions,','))) AS descriptions FROM tb;
```

Result:

```
 id | lng  | lat | descriptions 
----+------+-----+--------------
  1 | 0.98 |  51 | walk
  1 | 0.98 |  51 | wedding
  1 | 0.98 |  51 | bus
(3 rows)
```

Comment: If you are using regex then `regexp_split_to_table()` should be faster then a combination of `unnest()` and `regexp_split_to_array()`. But using a regex is not needed here and `string_to_array()` will be a faster than `regexp_split_to_array()`